# Assembly .Data Initialization of 4 bit value

Tags: assembly, x86

I'm trying to initialize a 4-bit binary sequence into an assembly program.

```
   .data 
x: .byte 00001111
```

I believe this should work for my problem but I'm wondering if there's a way to restrict it to just being the 4 least significant bits.

Is there a specific data type for just 4 bits?

Comment: I don't think you can use nibbles as 4 bit values are called. Most processors have 8 bit bytes as minimum. Question is why you would need to use less than 4 bits. You can always store 2 x 4 bits in a byte before / after your calculation (in case you've got many of them, otherwise there is probably no need).

Comment: i think this depends on the processor, but i assume your using a modern processor, so its not possible, as byte is the smallest size you can declare for it. why the constraint?

Comment: @MaartenBodewes and rcd: this is an assembler design decision.  You could easily design an assembler that operated in terms of bits, assembling a bit-stream.  You're right that it's motivated by CPUs having byte-addressable memory, though.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The minimum size of anything is 1 byte.  There no way to write two separate assembler directives that combine into a single byte.  You're using GNU `as` syntax, but this applies to all assemblers: they assemble *bytes* into the output.

The assembler's current output position (`.` in GNU syntax, `$` in NASM syntax) is always a whole number of bytes, not N bytes + M bits.  There are no `.nibble` or `.bit` directives.

This assembler design decision is separate from (but related to) the fact that memory is byte-addressable but not bit-addressable in modern hardware.  (i.e. if you want a bit, you have to load the containing byte and shift + mask it).

---

If you want to pack two separate nibbles into a byte, you need to combine them as the argument to a `.byte` directive (or .long or whatever) with an expression.  e.g.

```
x: .byte  0bABCD <<4 | 0bEFGH
```

to produce ABCDEFGH as a bit-string.  Note that `00001111` is [an octal constant (because of the leading 0 and no radix character)](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Binary-constants.html), not binary.  You need `0b` for that.

Some assemblers, like NASM, accept `010101b` (a suffix) as well, and some assemblers *only* support the suffix form.